# Where to download `Microsoft ole db provider for visual foxpro 9.0`?

Tags: visual-c++, foxpro

I'm planning to access `DBF` file using ADO, it seems that I need to install `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro 9.0`, but it reports 404 not found:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=14839

Do you know where can I download the provider?

What's the modern way to access `DBF`?

Answer (score 2):

CNET has the 9.0 driver available here:

[Microsoft OLD DB Provider for Visual FoxPro 9.0](https://download.cnet.com/Microsoft-OLE-DB-Provider-for-Visual-FoxPro-9-0/3000-10254_4-10729530.html)

JR

Answer (score 1):

The installer for the Visual FoxPro 9 OLEDB Driver appears to be gone from the Microsoft Download Center. Strangely the [Visual FoxPro 8 driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=32602) is still there. You could use that as long as you don't need features that were introduced in Version 9. You could also use the ODBC driver if you can find it.

Both the OLEDB and ODBC drivers from Microsoft are 32-bit, so your C++ application will need to be 32-bit.

There are various third-party alternatives out there for accessing DBF files:

[Devart ODBC Driver For XBase](https://www.devart.com/odbc/xbase/)

[Progress DataDirect](https://www.progress.com/odbc/dbase)

And various others. The thing to remember about third-party drivers is that they may or may not support indexes, and *none* of them support Visual FoxPro database stored procedures or triggers.

Answer (score 1):

The latest VFP OLE DB Provider (and ODBC Driver) are now available for download as part of the VFPX project:

https://github.com/VFPX/VFP9SP2Hotfix3